# datadog sinthetic json path, get value from key with character "-"

Tags: datadog

in datadog, in the steps from synthecis tests, i want to get a value from the response,  but the response have a key with especial character "-", example: my-simple-key
and I can't get it to read the value of that key

```
{
   "my-simple-key" : "my dummy value"
}
```

how can i do that?